# Problema con access y c#

Tags: c#, oledb

estoy ejecutando el siguiente código, en la quinta linea me da un error:

> "La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto"

```
costo = Convert.ToDouble(textBox8.Text);
string fecha = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
OleDbCommand actualizacion = new OleDbCommand("update servicios set estado_servicio = 'Finalizado', costo = @costo, fecha_entrega = '" + fecha + "' where clave = @parametro and estado_servicio = 'Reparacion'", conexion);
actualizacion.Parameters.AddWithValue("@costo", costo);
actualizacion.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parametro", Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text));
actualizacion.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Mi campo clave es un campo autonumerico*

Comment: Puedes mostrarnos que es lo que le lleva en "fecha"?

Comment: string fecha = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

Comment: Cual es el tipo de `fecha_entrega` en Access?

Comment: es de tipo texto corto

Comment: Hmm, entonces no es lo que pensaba. Cual es la línea que te da error exactamente? Es esta entonces: `... Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text)`? Si es el caso, entonces parece que `textBox4.Text` no te esta devolviendo un numero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dices que esta es la línea que te da error:

```
actualizacion.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parametro", Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text));
```

Eso significa que `textBox4.Text` no contiene un valor que pueda ser convertido a un entero.

Nota aparte, ya que estás usando parámetros para `@costo` y `@parametro` (te felicito), sería bueno que hicieras lo mismo con `fecha`.

Comment: gracias si era ese el problema

Answer (score 0):

Hola debería de validar los datos antes de persistirlos contra la base de datos, como por ejemplo si esta vacío y que el control TextBox te permita ingresar solo enteros o solo letras, podrias usar este control personalizado.

[TextBox-ComboBox](https://github.com/PedroAvila/TextBox-ComboBox)